# systemctl process restart detail logs

Tags: systemd

I have some service which is getting restart every 5-10 minutes due to some crash. The effect of this is that it restart's other services which are in "Require" and "After". Is there any way to find complete logs for systemctl.

Comment: You can try `journalctl -u <service_name>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo journalctl _PID=<pid>` if you know the PID. This can be useful in cases where the process was too short-lived for systemd to resolve the unit name.

Answer (score 0):

Full logging generated by `systemd` is available with:

```
journalctl
```

To see the log for a specific system unit, you can use:

```
journalctl --unit=<unit-name>
```

For a system unit or:

```
journalctl --user-unit=<unit-name> for a "user" unit.
```

There are [some cases in which the unit attribution is missing](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2913), so it can be good to review the full journal output around the time your service started or stopped to see if there is any additional related logging besides what you see with `journalctl --unit=`.